# Trouble with dropdown menu and what CSS to use when styling the parent menu button

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, css-selectors, parent-child

How do I keep the text in the parent button in the main menu indented when I hover over child menu options?

Here is my work in progress: http://sr.hi-speedinter.net/

The rollover state for the top level button in the main menu has a blue tab behind the button which requires some padding to be added when hovered over. In the off state, the menu wording has to vertically line up with content below it. In other words, the first child (labelled 'Staging') has to move horizontally depending on the state.

I have managed to keep the blue tabs applies when hovering over a child, but I just can't seem to affect the word in the first-child only.

I would have thought

```
.primary-navigation li:first-child:focus:active > a
```

would be correct, but it doesn't do what I expect.

I've done quite a bit of research and several times thought I had the answer..but no joy. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: I must be missing something....all of your nav buttons at the top, stay in line with the drop-down items on hover, except the first one (Staging). Why don't you just apply the same style to that one?

Comment: Sorry I managed to work it out, but was at work so I couldn't update my post until now. The answer was to apply the state to the parent eg ul.nav-menu > **li.menu-item:first-child:hover** > a